# Set background Image for a Custom UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am developing a paint application using OpenGL.

I am using "CUSTOM UIView" for drawing on a screen and another UIImageView to set background image to it. Have a look at screenshot to understand it clearly.. My problem is I am not able to set background image on either of the view.. I have to use different textures as a drawing board on which I have to Paint. Can anyone suggest what is incorrect in this approach??

[image: Imagelink]

I have used this code for custom UIView but not getting success.. but it shows white default  background only..

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder {
    UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Rough_White_Paper_with_tape.png"]];
    self.backgroundColor = background;
    [background release];     
}
```

Comment: I can not draw/painting anything after loading image to Custom UIView.. I will appreciate if someone can tell the reason for it..

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
NSURL *imgUrl=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/9794/screenshot20110802at345.png"];
NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgUrl];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];

imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];

[self addSubview:imageView ];
[self sendSubviewToBack:imageView ];

[imageView release]; [imgUrl release];
```

Comment: Should i use it in Custom UIView or UIImageView(I have shown two views in Screenshot)??

Comment: @ram: editing becomes available when you have enough reputation. rsp1990: this is an alternative, that creates a new UIImageView, that you'd insert into the parent view (so, behind the custom view with the drawing in it). All of the answers posted involve the same process. If you are just placing a UIImageView in the UI designer then you should be able to set the image right there.

Comment: I have used - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder.. I did not use ViewDidLoad.:|

Comment: @Tommy : can you tell me the problem of Drawing Disability???After using  this code I am not able to draw anything..

Comment: Is it possible you've added the new UIImageView as a sub of the custom UIView, and that it's the same size or larger? If so then it could just be on top of your drawing content, hiding the fact that anything is happening. Try adding it to the view controller's `self.view`.

Comment: @Tommy : Thanks..Thing is background image is being shown but actually the painting is drawn on original view which is covered by background image.. So i need drawing on background image... I hope you are getting what i am trying to explain..

Comment: Assuming the drawing view is transparent, surely that's the same as having the background image in the background and the drawing view on top?

Answer (score 29):

use this

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default"]];
```

Answer (score 26):

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Rough_White_Paper_with_tape.png"]];
        self.backgroundColor = background;
        [background release];
    }
    return self;
}
```

You just had to add return self; It works perfectly fine for me...

Comment: This works, but only if you use the image as-is; at least my brief test indicates that the tint colour is not taken into account.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Rough_White_Paper_with_tape.png"]];
[self addSubview:background];
[self sendSubviewToBack:background];
[background release];
```

Comment: Actually after using this approach it disables my painting/drawing on screen.. I am not able to draw anything..:(

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed :@“abc.png"]];
 UIView *myUIView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame :CGRectMake(10,10,250,250)];
 myUIView = myImageView;
```

Answer (score 2):

set background with UIImageView is not graceful。
should use following API:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteBackground.png"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

this is in swift 2

```
var background = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image.jpg"))
self.addSubview(background)
self.sendSubviewToBack(background)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```